# Localization of Model categories for $S\subsetneq S^{\prime}$

Tags: model-categories

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a model category that is cellular and proper.

Let $S\subsetneq S^{\prime}$ two sets of maps that we wish to localize our model structure.

By definition if $\mathscr{C}$ is a class of maps, then a fibrant object $W$ is $\mathscr{C}$-local if for every map $f:A\to B$, the induced map of function complexes
$$f^*:Map(B,W)\to Map(A,W)$$
is a weak equivalence.
Since $S\subsetneq S^{\prime}$, if an object $W$ is $S^{\prime}$-local, then this implies that it is also $S$-local and the converse cannot hold.
 Similarly a map $f:X\to Y$ is $S$-local equivalence if for every $S$-local object, the map of function complexes
$$f^*:Map(Y,Z)\to Map(X,Z) $$
is weak equivalence. Since every $S^{\prime}$-object is also a $S$-local object every $S$-local equivalence must also be $S^{\prime}$-local equivalence and the converse cannot hold.

Is the above correct? Or is there a counterexample?

Comment: Your definitions of local objects and local maps are wrong, you have to use derived (or homotopy) function complexes instead of ordinary (underived) function complexes.  Also, a proper inclusion of sets of maps can still give two identical classes of local objects.  For example, S' can be any subset of S-local equivalences that contains S, which gives the same class of local objects.

Comment: for the first thing, i am writing function complexes. I guess should have written homotopy function complexes.. But i was interested in simplicial model categories anyway.. For the second thing, i didnt had in mind such a degenerate case..

Comment: Having a simplicial model category doesn't help, the definitions are still wrong without deriving.  There is nothing degenerate about the second case: two localizations coincide if and only if S' consists of S-local equivalences.

Comment: i see... thanks for clearing it out to me.